# Asterisk exit when answer()

Tags: asterisk

My asterisk can move around the extension with "Goto()" but it exits immediately when meets the answer application. Could anyone help me to figure out the problem?

```
Executing [6138@from-sip-external:1] Goto("SIP/10.65.104.17-00000005", "kiem-tra-so-goi-vao,s,1") in new stack
-- Goto (kiem-tra-so-goi-vao,s,1)
-- Executing [s@kiem-tra-so-goi-vao:1] Answer("SIP/10.65.104.17-00000005", "") in new stack
== Spawn extension (kiem-tra-so-goi-vao, s, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/10.65.104.17-00000005'
```

Below is my dialplan:

```
[from-sip-external]
exten => 1234,1(dest-ext),Goto(kiem-tra-so-goi-vao,s,1)

[kiem-tra-so-goi-vao]
exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,n,Playback(hello-world)
exten => s,n,hangup()
```

Comment: can you show that part of dialplan

Comment: my dialplan is simple. I also find out when turn on rtp debug that my asterisk has neither received nor sent rtp. I have turned off the firewall in case it blocks some ports but it doesn't help

Comment: I don't think it's the problem. The dialplan works well when i test with xlite which locate in side the network. But when try to call from the outside network it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Most likly you have NAT or codec issues

To get more info you have enable sip debug

```
asterisk -r
sip set debug on
```

If you see in rtp part local ips, while connection from outside, that mean you have issues with nat.

IF you see "not acceptable here", that is codec.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it should be Hangup() not hangup(). I hope that will solve the problem. If not, most likely, codec mismatch is the culprit.
Change your last line to this.

```
same =>n, Hangup()
```